# Rules of using il, la, and dello in front of place name

Tags: word-usage

I used Google translate to get the following sentences. Notice the `il`, `la`, or `dello` are placed in front of the country names. Sometimes nothing is added to the country name. Is there a rule that I can follow if I do my own translation instead of using Google?

```
Distanza tra il Giappone e il Tagikistan
Distanza tra il Giappone e la Tailandia
Distanza tra il Giappone e Guatemala
Distanza tra il Giappone e dello Swaziland

Distanza tra il Tagikistan e il Giappone
Distanza tra la Thailandia e il Giappone
Distanza tra il Guatemala e il Giappone
Distanza tra Swaziland e il Giappone
```

Are the above translations correct? If I omit `il`, `la` etc. completely, will it be acceptable (maybe not ideal)?

```
Distanza tra Giappone e Tagikistan
Distanza tra Giappone e Tailandia
Distanza tra Giappone e Guatemala
Distanza tra Giappone e Swaziland

Distanza tra Tagikistan e Giappone
Distanza tra Thailandia e Giappone
Distanza tra Guatemala e Giappone
Distanza tra Swaziland e Giappone
```

Comment: Some country names always refuse the article (*Cipro*, *Andorra* and some others, but *Guatemala* is not among them). In the cases you mention, the article is either necessary everywhere, or you can omit it completely: *la distanza tra Giappone e Tagikistan è maggiore della distanza tra Lussemburgo e Andorra*.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find the rules you are looking for: http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-si-dice/I/il-lo.shtml (sorry, the link is in Italian).

Below the correct form:

```
Distanza tra il Giappone e il Tagikistan
Distanza tra il Giappone e la Tailandia
Distanza tra il Giappone e **il** Guatemala
Distanza tra il Giappone e **lo** Swaziland

Distanza tra il Tagikistan e il Giappone
Distanza tra la Thailandia e il Giappone
Distanza tra il Guatemala e il Giappone
Distanza tra **lo** Swaziland e il Giappone
```

Comment: Correct answer, but it seems that the OP needs something ever more basic, perhaps covering the fact that Italian nouns have two possible genders and the article has to agree with the noun.